# ADT plugin Error says Location of the android sdk has not been set up in the preferences

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I've downloaded Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) and installed Android ADT plugin using this link

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I'm getting error as 'Location of the android sdk has not been set up in the preferences'

[image: Error]

Where can i find the location of Android SDK path.
When we download the complete ADT bundle, we get two folder as 'eclipse' and 'sdk' but in my system there is no such folder as SDK.

I do not wish to download the ADT bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I created a folder named 'android-sdk'(in my Eclipse directory) and inside that folder i created another as tools

```
android-sdk
|-tools
```

and in Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences

I entered this folders path in 'SDK Location' text box. 
[image: sdk path]